# If I want to change the value of an object's instance variable, should I use 'set_value()' or 'object.value ='?

Tags: python

Here is an excerpt of my class:

```
Person:
   __init__(self, first_name):
      self.first_name = first_name
```

Should I create a function that allows me to get or change the value of the instance variable like this:

```
def set_first_name(self, first_name):
    self.first_name = first_name
```

Or is it okay to just use something like `person1.first_name = ...`?

Answer (score 0):

Do whatever you want (it's "ok"), a similar question was asked recently too in which I said that creating functions for such purposes will have a minimal overhead so unless you're using a function to externally set properties thousands of times, it won't matter.

It's obvious that without optimizations indexing and setting properties directly should be quicker (just quicker considering a nearly infinitesimal difference). Readability should be your biggest concern if you're considering dedicating a function to altering properties anyway.